# why is my getTag, setTag, getSelected, setSelected on checkbox is not giving me Toast I'm looking for

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, boolean

To me this seems to defy logic but...I know it doesn't because it's a computer I'm dealing with and I'm a human.

Regardless of whether my checkboxes are checked or unchecked, I'm getting `toast`:

```
'...clicked!'
```

If my `checkbox` is unchecked, I want to have the toast, `'...unclicked!'`

In my model, `SelectPhoneContact` I have:

```
//this is for the checkbox
    //by default, make it unchecked
    boolean isSelected = false;

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){

            isSelected = selected;

    }
```

I'm using `recyclerView`. In my `onBindViewHolder` I have:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        //bind the views into the ViewHolder
        //selectPhoneContact is an instance of the SelectPhoneContact class.
        //We will assign each row of the recyclerview to contain details of selectPhoneContact:

        //The number of rows will match the number of phone contacts
        final SelectPhoneContact selectPhoneContact = theContactsList.get(position);

        //if the row is a matching contact
        if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)

        {
            //in the title textbox in the row, put the corresponding name etc...
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).getSelected());
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);


            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                    Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();

                    if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected=true)
                    {
                      //  theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        //theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " unclicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected=true)` - You've got an assignment there, rather than the equality operator. Change `=` to `==`. Or just `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected)`.

Comment: Now, regardless of whether it is `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected==true)` or just `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected)` I get "`unclicked`". Any ideas?

Comment: For `Checkbox`es, you should be using an `OnCheckedChangeListener`, not an `OnClickListener`. You probably wanna un-comment those `setSelected()` calls, too.

Comment: Actually, when you switch to an `OnCheckedChangeListener`, a `boolean isChecked` will be passed into its method, so you could just pull the `setSelected()` calls out of the `if-else`, and do `setSelected(isChecked)`. (Looks like you've got the values backwards, anyway, as it is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike M's comments above, this works great:

```
 ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
           // ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new CompoundButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){

                    //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                    Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();

                    //set the value of the checkbox accordingly onCheckedChange,
                    //to true or false
                    theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(isChecked);

                    if(isChecked == true ) {
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " unclicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(isChecked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

In `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected=true)` you should have `==` or even better just write `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected)`.

Comment: Now, regardless of whether it is `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected==true)` or just `if (theContactsList.get(pos).isSelected)` I get "`unclicked`". Any ideas?

Comment: @CHarris did you uncomment setSelected call?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's commented or not, it makes no difference - it's still 'unclicked'. I think Mike M above is on right track, looking into it now.